# JavaFX isn't printing a grid on a BorderPane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to write a simple sudoku interface in JavaFX using text fields, however when I try to generate the grid, it simply does not show up. I assume that there may be a problem with the fxml file, but I don't know whether it's even necessary.

I tried to use Gluon SceneBuilder, but I intend to avoid generating it manually, inasmuch as it generates excessive amount of code.

My game controlling component is as follows:

```
public class GameController implements Initializable {

    public Pane gamePane;

    @FXML
    private GridPane gridPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        gridPane = new GridPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < SudokuBoard.ROW_NUM; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SudokuBoard.ROW_NUM; j++) {
                TextField field = new TextField(String.valueOf(0));
                field.setFont(Font.font(24));
                gridPane.add(field, i, j);
            }
        }

        gamePane.getChildren().add(gridPane);

    }
}
```

and my fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<BorderPane fx:id="gamePane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <Label fx:id="gameLabel" text="Sudoku Game" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <center>
      <GridPane/>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

I think manipulating the code this way could produce the expected result, but it does not. Could it be that the fxml file hinders the automatic generation of grid pane text fields?

Comment: That `GridPane` looks empty to me.  Perhaps you should put something in each grid square, for however many grid squares you want for your game.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this too, but it would make the generation of text fields in a loop unnecessary

Comment: There is no loop. There is no controller used with the fxml either. Either this is is a pretty obvious mistake or you didn't post the relevant parts of the code...

Comment: @fabian thanks for your remark, I posted the content of a wrong file.

Comment: I think you should verify it actually runs the `initialize` method.  I took your code, and I added a `fx:controller` parameter with the controller class name, and the grid was generated properly then.

Answer (score 1):

The problems I saw were all missing a few things but after fixing it ran well for me first off you had no controller connected to the fxml you may actually not need this depending on how you load your fxml(Which I can't see)

I just had to add this section to the boarderpane part

```
fx:controller="FXMLFolder.Controller"
```

or depending on your project structure

```
fx:controller="Controller"
```

like so

```
<BorderPane fx:id="gamePane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" 
        prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
        fx:controller="FXMLTests.Controller">
```

Next you call a gridpane that looks like its attached to the fxml because the annotation but its not as you don't have the `fx:id` in the fxml like so change this

```
<GridPane/>
```

to

```
<GridPane fx:id="gridPane"/>
```

try to stay consistent when declaring your variable so you don't confuse others reading your code so match up

```
public Pane gamePane;
@FXML
private GridPane gridPane;
```

to

```
public Pane gamePane;
public GridPane gridPane;
public Label gameLabel;//I added this because you have an `fx:id` in your fxml
```